# How to use json in intent functions in dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I'm making an application for google home as graduation work from my university of systems analysis and development. My difficulty is integrating with an external server.

I'm doing the code in javaScript, node.js and my intents call data from an external service, the server of the company, there is authentication, but even with Json without validation I can not access the data.

I used some examples of the google channel itself in youtube and the documentation of DialogFlow but I can not.

Has someone already done something similar and can you help me?

[image]

Comment: image of an example of the test function without authorization that also does not work, with authorization or without authorization the result and the same

Comment: Currently, this looks like an off-topic question or at least it needs some editing. Instead, you should provide a minimal example of what you have tried with the code you have and describe what problem you got stuck with. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can find some information about how to ask a good question. Otherwise, you won't find any help and there is a chance your question will be closed.

Comment: You say you are using Dialogflow - are you using the built-in code editor, or are you using another service? If so, what service? Can you update your question to include more of the code that isn't working and any errors or anything else that you're getting that makes you think it isn't working? (Including the code as text rather than an image is better.)